# Making a docker image for use with an R package. Can I make a Github action that tests installing the package on the image?

Tags: docker, github-actions, r-package

I have an R package for internal use with a fair number of linux and R dependencies. I'd like to test if the package can be installed on a fresh container from a custom docker image. I have separate actions set up to run R-CMD-CHECK on the package and to build/push the image, but is there an action I can create to run on pushes to the dockerfile that check if the package can be installed? Both the package and the dockerfile repo are hosted on Github and are public. The image is an extension of rocker/rstudio with some linux libraries installed.

I am quite new to actions so I am still working on understanding how to make a custom action to chain the building of a custom image and the R install together. Most of the actions I've found for docker are relating to pushing the image to dockerhub. I don't want to have the package installed as part of the dockerfile either, since the R dependencies and versioning are quite mutable. I just want the docker image to have the necessary linux libraries to then install all the necessary R packages.